# How can transpose mongodb document list to tabular form?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb-query

How can transpose mongodb document list to tabular form?

Example:

**I have the following list of BsonDocuments**

```
[0] = { "_id" : ObjectId("546ce80d43f5c2b7d8a713bd"), "Address" : "61- A, Pocket- C, Ram Vihar Phase II, UP", "Pincode" : 110091, "Locality" : "Mayur Vihar Phase II", "City" : "Delhi", "Latitude" : 28.618156, "Longitude" : 76.3055877 }

[1] = { "_id" : ObjectId("546ce80d43f5c2b7d8a713bd"), "Address" : "61- A, Pocket- C,  Phase II, Rahi", "Pincode" : 110091, "Locality" : "Mayur Vihar Phase II", "City" : "Delhi", "Latitude" : 28.618156, "Longitude" : 77.305877 }

[2] = { "_id" : ObjectId("546ce80d43f5c2b7d8a713bd"), "Address" : "6 B2C - C, Krish Marg II, Delhi", "Pincode" : 110092, "Locality" : "Mayur Vihar Phase II", "City" : "Delhi", "Latitude" : 28.618156, "Longitude" : 76.305877 }
```

**And I want convert this list to tabular like json like**

```
Address:{'61- A, Pocket- C, Ram Vihar Phase II, UP',' '61- A, Pocket- C,  Phase II, Rahi ','6 B2C - C, Krish Marg II, Delhi'} ,
Pincode:{'110091','110091','110092'},
...
```

Similarly for all fields.

So my question is:
is there any library or do I need write code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write code to aggregate, which may look like:

- `Group` by `_id` equal to `null`, so that all the records come under
  the same group.
- Use the `$push` operator to form an array of Address, Pincode,..
  elements.
- `Project` the required fields omitting the `_id` field.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":null,"Address":{$push:"$Address"},"Pincode":{$push:"$Pincode"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"Address":1,"Pincode":1}}
])
```

You can include other fields like `Locality`,.. as well.

If you want to do it in the client side:

```
var result = {};
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
var keys = Object.keys(doc);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
{
        if(!result[keys[i]]) result[keys[i]] = [];
        result[keys[i]].push(doc[keys[i]]);
}
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i have dynamic fields ( fields name are not certain)

Comment: @deepak.mhr See my updated answer to show how it is done during post processing.